# MariaDB does not finish query for table with foreign key

Tags: mariadb

In a MariaDB data base I've set up I cannot change tables with foreign keys *at all*. Querys involving `alter table` and `drop table` never finish, I don't even get an error message. Same with `repair table`.

All I can do is hit ctrl+c. There are no apparent errors indicated in the InnoDB monitor output.

I'm quite new to relational data bases, so it's probably a user error. I just can't see what it might be. Any help greatly appreciated!

- OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
- MariaDB: 10.8
- using both the client and a plugin in Visual Studio Code, doesn't matter.
- I can alter other tables.
- I set `foreign_key_checks` to `off`

The table with the foreign key looks like below. `participant_id` is the foreign key.

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| trial_id | smallint(6) | NO | PRI | NULL |  |
| begin_trial | datetime | NO | UNI | NULL |  |
| participant_id | tinyint(4) | NO | MUL | NULL |  |

The referenced table looks like this, `id` is `participant_id`.

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | tinyint(4) | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| code | char(6) | NO | UNI | NULL |  |
| day | date | NO |  | 0000-00-00 |  |

Answer (score 0):

Yes, user error. I had two connections open, one using the MariaDB client, another one using the VSC plugin. Thus there must have been some kind of lock on write operationsm but not on read operations.

Thanks for being my rubber duck, Stackoverflow.